# Angular 2 переадресация, если уже создан магазин с этим id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, angular2

Не понимаю, как можно реализовать редирект на другую страницу, если пользователь с id(this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id) уже создал с данным id магазин.

Пробовал так, но не работает

Shop.component.ts

```
owner_id :number;    
private sub: any;
ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.httpService.getShops().subscribe(params => {
       this.owner_id = this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id ;
    console.log(this.sub)
        console.log(this.owner_id)
    });
    if (this.sub) {
      this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
    }
```

Http.service.ts

```
getShops(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/shops.json')
}
```

Api - Rails 5.
Для аутентификации пользователей пользуюсь auth token.
Два дня не понимаю, как сделать. Спасибо за внимание и за помощь.

Comment: Что выводит в консоль console.log(this.sub)? В любом случае нужно if (this.sub) {
      this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
    } внести внутрь subscribe, так как он асинхронный

Comment: Автоматическую переадресацию делает. Сначало это показывает  `Object { closed: true, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: false, isStopped: true, destination: Object }  main.bundle.js:382:13`        Потом это показывает                        
`Object { closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array[1], syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: false, isStopped: false, destination: Object }`

Comment: так это все не так. Начнем с того что вы хотите в sub записать?

Comment: сбросьте этот файл shops.json

Comment: Записать я не хочу . Нужно только чтоб сравнить json файле есть ли (owner_id) текущего  пользователя т.е. this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id сам json файл `[{"id":1,"name":"test","about":"tetetetete","opening":"155522225","closing":"455445","cover":null,"logo":null,"owner_id":null,"created_at":"2017-04-19T11:19:22.000Z","updated_at":"2017-04-19T11:19:22.000Z"},{"id":2,"name":"test2","about":"asfasfasf","opening":"234234","closing":"234234","cover":null,"logo":null,"owner_id":null,"created_at":"2017-04-20T10:02:54.000Z","updated_at":"2017-04-20T10:02:54.000Z"}]`

Comment: просто вы не понимаете как работает http.get. Он возвращает Observable и не нужно к нему приравнивать, а нужно в подписке получить. this.httpService.getShops().subscribe(params => { this.sub = params } Здесь params и есть масив который вы получили. Если нет то нужно вызвать params.json(). И с этим масивом уже ищите. так же и с другим запросом.

Comment: Сделал subscribe(params => {}  так как вы сказали но в  console.log одно и тоже показывает и еще this.owner_id показывает как undefined

Comment: this.httpService.getShops().subscribe(params => { console.log(params)}) что вывело?

Comment: Вывело одну запись с  shops.json `Object { _body: "[{"id":1,"name":"test","about":"tet…", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, type: 2, url: "http://localhost:3000/shops.json" }`

Comment: ну одну Значит нужно this.httpService.getShops().subscribe(params => { console.log(params.json())}). Выведет масив записей. Потом здесь следующий запрос.

Comment: Спасибо вам . Каким методом можно сделать проверку есть ли this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id в базе магазин на данного пользователя и если есть чтоб redirect работал